# DidFinishNavigation never gets called when I use iframe

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to load some webpages inside of **WKWebView**. I want to display a loading spinner on the screen when webview is loading and hide it once the page finishes loading (specifically when **DidFinishNavigation** gets called), but **DidFinishNavigation** never gets called when the page that is loading contains an iframe element in HTML, because of that, I'm not able to hide the loading spinner.

Please let me know why this happened and if there is any workarounds for this issue.

For example:

Web Code

```
<section id="Document">
    <iframe  src="SomeOtherPages"></iframe>
    <div id="Loader"></div>
</section>
```

XAMARIN Code

```
  public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            var userController = new WKUserContentController();

            // add JS function to the document so we can call it from C#
            userController.AddUserScript(
                new WKUserScript(
                    new NSString(Global.MessageHandlerFunction),
                    WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, false));

            // register messageHandler 'native' that can be called with window.webkit.messageHandlers.native
            userController.AddScriptMessageHandler(this, "native");

            var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };

            webView = new WKWebView(View.Frame, config) { WeakNavigationDelegate = this };
            webView.AllowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true;
            webView.UIDelegate = this;
            webView.NavigationDelegate = this;

            View.AddSubview(webView);
            this.loadingOverlay = new LoadingOverlay(View.Frame);
            View.AddSubview(loadingOverlay);

            webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(defaultUrl)));
        }

        [Export("webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:")]
        public void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, Action<WKNavigationActionPolicy> decisionHandler)
        {
            decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow);
            Console.WriteLine("DecidePolicy " + webView.Url);
            SetLoadingOverlay(false);    
        }

        public void SetLoadingOverlay(bool hide){
            InvokeOnMainThread(()=>{
                UIView.Animate(0.5, () => { loadingOverlay.Hidden = hide; });
            });
        }

        [Export("webView:didFinishNavigation:")]
        public void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Finish Loading...");
            SetLoadingOverlay(true);
        }

        [Export("webView:didFailNavigation:withError:")]
        public void DidFailNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation, NSError error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed Loading...");
            SetLoadingOverlay(true);
        }

        [Export("webView:didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError:")]
        public void DidFailProvisionalNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation, NSError error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed Loading...");
            SetLoadingOverlay(true);
        }
```

Comment: You mean it works fine without iFrame in web content?

Comment: Yes, but when my web content contains iframe, DidFinishNavigation never gets called so I cannot hide the loading spinner.